# Using Hibernate or JDBC when I need one row from a large table

Tags: database, hibernate, jdbc

1>Table with millions row and 100 columns I want to run a query which will return one row (and I need 3-4 column) from the table. Which of JDBC or Hibernate is a better option for this  use case.

2>Also is there any risk of getting Out Of Memory if we use hibernate in this case. I do not have any idea about caching issues in hibernate and heard people get OOM.

3>Which of hibernate/JDBC will give faster result. As the time matters in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can do this easily with Hibernate, just use a "view object". Performance will be the same as with native JDBC.
2. No, Hibernate will only process what's returned in the Resultset. If that only contains one row, there won't be any problem.
3. Hibernate will be slow in two cases: it generates sub-optimal queries (you can tune this with .hbm config file and/or annotations) or slow to process the results (this happens when the returned Resultset is huge).

By the way, see my blog entry on using [Hibernate for OLAP style queries](http://www.istvandevai.com/2012/06/jpa-query-result-as-pojo.html).

Answer (score 0):

If this is a project which already is using hibernate then there is no reason not to use hibernate. See Istvan Devai's answer.

If this is a new project and this is all you do with the db I do not think there is much benefit in using hibernate (or any other JPA implementation) and you are better of using plain JDBC.